# user insert into course as shown I want the course_limit to increment by 1 for that user

Tags: php

Let's say I have two tables as shown:

user

> id    plan   course_limit  username
>
> 10                  0        ahmad

note: plan is enum field containing '','a','b','c'.

course

> id    user_id   username
>
> 1       10        ahmad

Now I want when a user insert into course as shown I want the course_limit to increment by 1 for that user so that I can apply a limit.

now i don,t want to use triggers as my hosting does not support so i want to use php and do this. plz help me.

Comment: Your requirement doesn't make a lot of sense. Can you tell us a bit more about how your system should work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run an `UPDATE` statement after you run the `INSERT`.

(If you are using MySQL) Ex:

```
UPDATE user SET course_limit=course_limit+1 WHERE username = '$username'
```